# What are water sleeves? ("For a few seconds their ankles glittered in rippling sleeves of retreating water.")

Tags: metaphors, literature

> A wave, pushed by one behind it, slid so far up the slant of sand, their feet were delicately shocked and soaked. For a few seconds their ankles glittered in rippling *sleeves* of retreating *water*.

What are water sleeves?

Answer (score 5):

A sleeve is not only a part of a shirt / clothing, but in a more figurative sense a sheath-like object that surrounds something.

In your example, the water flows around and possibly somewhat up the ankles of the persons described, forming "water socks":

[image: http://cache3.asset-cache.net/gc/98324376-wave-feet-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&]

[source](http://www.gettyimages.in/detail/photo/wave-feet-high-res-stock-photography/98324376).